# Accessing map inside union inside class gives segmentation fault

Tags: c++, stl, unions

I am trying to create a class which either contains a map of one type or another, so I decided to use an anonymous union. But my code gives a segmentation fault when I try to access the map (in this case I get a segfault in both the constructor and the destructor):

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
    private:
        union
        {
            std::map<std::string, int> ints;
            std::map<std::string, std::string> strings;
        };

        bool fooContainsInts;

    public:

        Foo(bool containsInts) : fooContainsInts(containsInts) 
        {
            if (containsInts) {ints = std::map<std::string, int>();}
            else {strings = std::map<std::string, std::string>();}
        }

        ~Foo()
        {
            if (fooContainsInts) {ints.clear();}
            else {strings.clear();}
        }
};  

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "No segfault here!" << std::endl;
    Foo foo(true);
    std::cout << "This line doesn't get printed" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use placement new to construct the map and manually call its destructor. If you do some searches for "C++ unrestricted union" you'll find lots of good resources.

Comment: You don't want to declare class with templates, do you?

Comment: @MikeCAT No, this is just a simplified version of something else I'm trying to do, which needs a union with two maps

Comment: Just have 2 maps and use one, you are creating a big headache just to save a couple bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest templating the type instead of a union, but maybe this helps you.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union

The second example shows you how to deal with non-POD union members.

It should look like this

```
    Foo(bool containsInts) : fooContainsInts(containsInts) 
    {
        if (containsInts) { new (&ints) std::map<std::string, int>;}
        else { new (&strings) std::map<std::string, std::string>;}
    }

    ~Foo()
    {
        if (fooContainsInts) { ints.~map<std::string, int>(); }
        else { strings.~map<std::string, std::string>(); }
    }
```

I cant test it on MSCV though right now.

You need to explicitly construct and destruct non-POD union types

Answer (score 2):

Most STL containers including the `std::map` type cannot be in a union since it has "non-trivial" member functions.  See [wiki](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/union) for further information on what can and cannot be inside of a union.

A union is used to share the memory between multiple data types.  Note that the `std::map` container will **heap** allocate the memory needed to store the actual data for each node.  Those heap allocations would not be in the union.